# What is the proper way of doing Pauli arithmetic in Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, programming

To my understanding, the `WeightedPauliOperator` class in discontinued, and should no longer be used when dealing with Pauli operators. So how should I perform arithmetic with paulis?
$$
( 3 X_1 Y_3 + 5 Z_2 X_0 ) (Z_3+2X_2X_4) = \ \text{(expanded version)}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The legacy operators in Qiskit Aqua (like `WeightedPauliOperator`) were replaced by
the operator flow function. The documentation for that replacement is here: https://github.com/Qiskit/rfcs/blob/master/0003-Aqua_0.7_operator_redesign.ipynb

However, the class is not deprecated and you are free to use it, even when it lives in the legacy module.